# How can I convert a configure script to a CMakeLists file?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, configure

I'm wanting to use [this library](http://spiral.net/software/sfft.html) in my cmake project, however it comes with a `configure` file instead of `CMakeLists.txt`

```
#! /bin/sh
# waf configure wrapper
# based on http://code.google.com/p/waf/source/browse/configure

CUR_DIR=$PWD

#possible relative path
WORKINGDIR=`dirname $0`
cd $WORKINGDIR
#abs path
WORKINGDIR=`pwd`
cd $CUR_DIR
WAF=$WORKINGDIR/tools/waf

# Generates a Makefile. Requires that $WAF is set.
#
generateMakefile()
{
    cat > Makefile << EOF
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# Waf Makefile wrapper
WAF_HOME=$CUR_DIR

all:
    @$WAF build

all-debug:
    @$WAF -v build

all-progress:
    @$WAF -p build

install:
    $WAF install --yes;

uninstall:
    $WAF uninstall

clean:
    @$WAF clean

distclean:
    @$WAF distclean
    @-rm -rf build
    @-rm -f Makefile

check:
    @$WAF check

dist:
    @$WAF dist

.PHONY: clean dist distclean check uninstall install all

EOF
}

generateMakefile

"${WAF}" configure $*
exit $?
```

Are there automated tools for the conversion? Does CMake supoprt the use of configure files? Is there a rule of thumb for conversion - i.e. replace `...` with `add_library`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert an upstream library to cmake to be able to use it in cmake projects.  As long as you're able to install and/or link to that library, you can configure your cmake project to use it.

A common pattern to consume third-party libraries with cmake is to use cmake's `find_package()` function by supplying your own special-purpose cmake module files to find and configure the library.

Say, you're hoping to load libfoo. [Here are the steps:](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries)

- create a directory within your project tree to store your custom cmake modules (say, `./cmake/modules`)
- in that directory create a text file named `FindFoo.cmake`.
- Within `FindFoo.cmake` add checks to determine if foo is actually present in the system. If it is then set the relevant variables.  Otherwise, throw an error.  The ideal thing is to create a build target for that library, which you can simply add as dependencies to other cmake targets.
- Configure your cmake project to use your local modules by adding `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/")`,
- Finally, configure your cmake project to include your Foo library by calling `find_package(Foo REQUIRED)`.

Comment: How will cmake import the library (setup as a module)? Does it compile it using the configure script?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi this approach only covers importing a pre-existing third-party library to a cmake project.  With this approach you can check if the library exists, and define all the cmake variables you need to import and link to the library.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do the conversion is to read the configure script and understand what it does and how/why. Then write a CMakeLists.txt file that achieves the same.

There are no shortcuts.

Comment: Would It be better to try and built a static lib using configure/make, and then just link to that with cmake? I don't know how configure/make works - and from what I have heard it's not something worth learning

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi That's certainly an alternative.